# Cassandra DB: Parsing an Instant from Cassandra's Timestamp in Json fails

Tags: java, database, parsing, cassandra, timestamp

Lets say I've an one-column-table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id int,
time timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Now I insert data per Json:

```
INSERT INTO test JSON '{"id":1,"time":"2018-01-12T15:06:02.753Z"}'
```

The result would look like this:

```
id        time
1         2018-01-12 15:06:02.753+0000
```

Now I select the entry again as Json:

```
SELECT JSON * from test where id=1;
```

The resulting Json would look like this:

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "time":"2018-01-12 15:06:02.753+0000"
}
```

If I now want to parse the field "time" in the json above to an Instant, it fails because of a whitespace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-01-12 10:23:00.461Z' could not be parsed at index 10
```

I could replace the whitespace-Charakter with a 'T'-Delimiter, but is there an better way to parse an Instant?

Comment: How do you access data? via some remote web service? If not - why you need JSON, and not access data directly via java driver?

Comment: I need Json because its for me easier to handle afterwards..and yes im using the java driver

Comment: Can you add the Java code which is doing the parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datastax Java driver supports table to object mapping out-of-the box. You don't have to write the code by yourself.

Timestamps are automatically mapped to `java.util.Date` objects by Java driver. See some related documentation below:

- [Documentation of Object mapper for Java
  driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/object_mapper/)
- [Some code examples on how to map Java objects to tables](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/object_mapper/creating/)
- [Mapping between Java types and CQL
  types](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/)